# Multiple iPads need multiple games

Tags: game-center, clash-of-clans

I have 4 kids and they all have games on their iPads that are the same games.  How do I get the accounts squared away so they are no playing each others game?  For example, everyone has "Clash of the clans" on their iPads and they all play the same game.  How can we get it so each person can create their own world in the game and not interfere with each others' game?

Answer (score 1):

If you ensure that each device has a distinct iCloud account so that the Documents and Data for each device is stored in a separate account, you can have the 4 devices all share one Apple ID for purchasing and have a separate account for each child's mail, contacts, messages, etc...

Answer (score -1):

As I understand it, iOS games keep their save states associated with a particular Apple ID and its associated Game Center username. You could definitely have different save states on different iPads for different children if they had different Apple IDs - however, be warned that this will mean that you'll have to buy the game independently for each Apple ID if it's not free.
Some games, however, will allow you to have multiple save states under the same ID. I'm not sure if this is the case with Clash of the Clans - I'm not familiar with it.

As patrix noted below, it may be possible to download the same game to multiple devices with multiple accounts - I'm still unsure if this will interfere with online behaviour/Game Center interaction, however.

Comment: That's not entirely correct. You can install an application on several devices without buying it again, either by syncing with the same iTunes or by logging into the App Store in the iPhone and downloading the app again.

Comment: You don't have to use the same AppleID to play a game (aka log into GameCenter) as you used to download/buy it :-)

Comment: I regularly test Games using a sandbox Game Center account which is different than the iCloud account for game storage which in turn is different than the account used to purchase the Apps. Game status follows the iCloud D&D account and nothing else. GC is used for match making and some game achievement storage, but most people use the same account for GC/iCloud Documents and Data so there's never a need to know which is storing the files.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm new here - what's the protocol when my answer is so obviously outclassed? Delete it? Add an edit to say so?

Comment: Feel free to include the feedback from the comments into your answer.